# tsearch2 word statistics

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with a tsvector in my table. Now I'd like to find out witch words are represented above average, to add these to the stop word list. Is there a function for tsearch2 to list the frequency of all words in the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT ts_vector_col FROM mytable') 
ORDER BY nentry DESC, ndoc DESC, word ;
```

[Gathering Document Statistics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-STATISTICS)